# Get the values of child tags based on the value of another child tag

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

Assuming that I have a `LONGTEXT` column in MySQL that contains the following value

```
<Parent1> 
    <Parent2>
        <Parent3>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Testing 1</name>
            <age>10</age>
        </Parent3>

        <Parent3>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Testing 2</name>
            <age>5</age>
        </Parent3>
    </Parent2>
</Parent1>
```

I want to extract the values for child tags `name` and `age` where the `id` of `Parent3` is equal to `2` but I am not quite sure what xpath should I pass to [`extractValue`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) in order to achieve this.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one xpath to get the results I see 2 ways of doing this

**1 :**

```
//Parent3[id = 2]/name/text()|//Parent3[id = 2]/age/text()
```

**2 :**

```
//Parent3[id = 2]/*[self::name|self::age]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
//Parent3[id=2]/name/text()
//Parent3[id=2]/age/text()
```

To extract values of `name` and `age` children of `Parent3` that contain `id` equal to `2`